# Does changing web hosting affect search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, pagerank

I have been hosting in a server from last 2 years. I am planning to change the hosting server. Before I change the hosting server I would like to know whether it affects my site's rankings or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. And why should it? Your hosting has nothing to do with the quality or relevancy of your content. (1)

Just try to minimize downtime and avoid if possible. A seamless transition is ideal.

(1) Really slow loading webpages may cause google to lower your page rankings but you have to be in the bottom 1% or so for this to happen. So as long as your host isn't poor you will be fine.

Comment: Some of the SEO companies say that the webhosting matters as about 25% in the ranking. So there is no truth in that?

Comment: Those SEO companies are perfect examples of why it's so hard to get good SEO information. They're flat out wrong.

Comment: I am really a fan of your experience in SEO. I have posted another separate question for it and linked [it](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/web-hosting-does-not-matter).

Comment: I think it's actually too broad a question to give a firm answer to. Assuming all else is equal, simply being on a different server shouldn't matter. But impact on load speed could affect ranking, CTR, PPC, etc; server IP address can, in certain circumstances, be an issue for geotargeting. So not a flat out "no", but "probably not".

Answer (score 14):

As long as your domain name **and hosting country stay the same**, switching from one reliable host to another should have no SEO impact. See question 4 in this [Seomoz article link](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/matt-cutts-movie-marathon)

Comment: The point about hosting country should be noted. It may have impact in some cases because a website hosted in a country usually gets more SEO points for search results in that country.

Answer (score 4):

In a similar vein as John Conde's suggestion (though picking up on a few things I've noticed) you can also expect problems when switching hosts if your new host has security issues.

If you share an Apache server with malicious users, you may find some problems including malicious content *apparently hosted* under your domain if your host has not disabled features like Apache's [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html) (it doesn't help to be recognized as a phishing or malware site)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually, it can!

If the new host is permissive and has issues with quality sites, hacker activity, spamming (all types), and past issues with search engines, your site could be given an IP address that is either specifically known or within a block that is known as a bad neighborhood. As well, the host itself can be considered as a bad neighborhood. Google tracks not only IP addresses and IP address blocks, but hosts that are known for these issues. Not choosing a high quality host can literally drop you from search existence almost over night (actually over a period of just a few days). This is also true for using a CDN and is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not effect your links on the internet since your just changing ip's the url of your content should stay the same ultimately