# Web hosting does not matter?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, ranking

I have read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/does-changing-web-hosting-server-affects-seo-page-ranking) question. I agree that webhosting does matter in load time and how much uptime it is giving but it seems that some companies have given it a huge hype. Please have a look at this example,
[image]

They claim that in SEO, 23.8% is which hosting you use. Please clear out is it a gimmick or it carries some weight. Thanks

Comment: Trust of the hosting **domain** != hosting provider. Your domain's trust is dependent on who you've linked with and your avoidance of banned SEO techniques. The worry with hosting providers comes from block lists that use IP addresses if you're on a shared server, but that's a whole 'nuther discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reading that wrong. They're talking about the domain name, not the hosting company.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So, domain host does count that much?

Comment: Some people like to think so. I don't. At least as much as the trust and authority goes. Keywords in the domain are very good to have, though.

Comment: this also depends on when this pie chart was made, google now sees exact match urls as potential spam ie. best-hosting-company.com might be picked since to panda. Not in all cases but in some, its a part of overoptimization